# @time in julia prints different time

Tags: julia

I started translating some of my Matlab scripts to Julia and trying to compare the performance. Here I came across a seemly simple question, but I did not find the answer by a quick search. When I run the Julia script from console, i.e. type "julia test_FAS2SA.jl", it prints "3.116226 seconds" on the screen, which is almost 30  times the running time of the corresponding matlab script.

Then I entered the julia environment and type "include("test_FAS2SA.jl")", it prints "1.368429 seconds". However, when I just type "@time SA,PF=FAS2SA(FAS1,f_FAS,10.0,f_SA, 0.05);", it prints "0.033920 seconds". I am wondering what is the real running time for function FAS2SA and different time is printed.

My platform is Windows 7 professional, Julia 1.10. The script "test_FAS2SA.jl" and input files are pasted as below.

```
# test JuliaFunc
using DelimitedFiles

# import Pkg; Pkg.add("time")
using QuadGK 

function getH_SDF(D,fn,freq)
# PURPOSE
#   get transfer function of a SDOF oscilator
#   acc response to acc excitation
# INPUT
#   D - damping ratio
#   fn - fundamental frequency of the SDOF (Hz)
#   freq - frequency array (Hz)
# OUTPUT
#   absH - Amplitude of the transfer function

N=length(freq)
    H=complex(zeros(N))
for i=1:N
    f=freq[i]
    H[i]=(-fn^2)/((f^2-fn^2)-(2*f*fn*D*1im))
end
return abs.(H)

end

function trapz(x, y)
# Trapezoidal integration rule
local n = length(x)
if (length(y) != n)
    error("Vectors 'x', 'y' must be of same length")
end
r = 0.0
if n == 1; return r; end
for i in 2:n
    r += (x[i] - x[i-1]) * (y[i] + y[i-1])
end

#= correction -h^2/12 * (f'(b) - f'(a))
ha = x[2] - x[1]
he = x[end] - x[end-1]
ra = (y[2] - y[1]) / ha
re = (y[end] - y[end-1]) / he
r/2 - ha*he/12 * (re - ra)
=#

return r/2
end

function getmoment(Y,f,n)

N=length(Y)
S=zeros(N)
for i=1:N
    S[i]=(2.0*pi*f[i])^n*Y[i]^2
end
return 2.0*trapz(f,S)

end

function getXmax(Y,F,T_rms)

moment0=getmoment(Y,F,0)
moment2=getmoment(Y,F,2)
moment4=getmoment(Y,F,4)

Y_rms=(moment0/T_rms)^0.5  # rms value

Ne=1.0/pi*(moment4/moment2)^0.5*T_rms  # number of extrema
xi=(moment2^2/moment0/moment4)^0.5  # number of width
#temp=(2*log(xi*Ne))^0.5 
#PF(i)=temp+0.5772/temp 

Func(x)=1-(1-xi*exp(-x^2))^Ne

#Fun=@(x) 1-(1-xi.*exp(-x.^2)).^Ne
Tmp,e = QuadGK.quadgk(Func,0,Inf)
PF = sqrt(2.0)*Tmp

Ymax=PF*Y_rms
return Ymax
end

function FAS2SA(FAS,F,T_gm,freq, damping)
# INPUT
#   FAS  - Fourier Amplitude Spectrum
#   F    - Frquency array corresponding FAS (Hz)
#   T_gm - ground motion duration (sec)
#   freq - fundametnal frequency of SDOF oscilator (Hz)
#   damping - damping ratio of SDOF oscilator
# OUTPUT
#   SA   - Spectral acceleration (g)
#   PF   - Peak Factor 

n_T=length(freq)
SA=zeros(n_T)
PF=zeros(n_T)

for i=1:n_T

H=getH_SDF(damping,freq[i],F) # get transfer function of SDOF oscilator
Y=FAS.*H  # FAS of acc response of oscilator
Tn=1.0/freq[i]  # fundamantal period
T0=Tn/2.0/pi/damping  #oscilator duration
gamma=T_gm/Tn  

n_val=3.0  
alpha=1.0 / 3.0

T_rms=T_gm+T0*(gamma^n_val/(gamma^n_val+alpha)) # total duration


moment0=getmoment(Y,F,0)
moment2=getmoment(Y,F,2)
moment4=getmoment(Y,F,4)

Y_rms=(moment0/T_rms)^0.5  # rms value

Ne=1/pi*(moment4/moment2)^0.5*T_gm  # number of extrema
# note that here use T_gm not T_rms (Refer to Boore and Joyer, 1984)

xi=(moment2^2/moment0/moment4)^0.5  # number of width
#temp=(2*log(xi*Ne))^0.5 
#PF(i)=temp+0.5772/temp 

Fun(x)= 1-(1-xi*exp(-x^2))^Ne
Q_tmp,e_tmp = QuadGK.quadgk(Fun,0,Inf)
PF1 = 2^0.5*Q_tmp



Ymax=PF1*Y_rms  

SA[i]=Ymax
PF[i]=PF1


end
return (SA,PF)
end 

T=readdlm("period.dat")
f_SA=1.0 ./ T

#println(vs)

FAS=readdlm("FAS.dat")
f_FAS=FAS[:,1]
FAS1=FAS[:,2]

println(@time SA,PF=FAS2SA(FAS1,f_FAS,10.0,f_SA, 0.05))
```

file "period.dat"

```
    0.01
0.01103674
0.012180962
0.01344381
0.014837583
0.016375854
0.018073604
0.019947366
0.022015388
0.024297811
0.026816861
0.029597071
0.032665516
0.036052079
0.039789741
0.043914901
0.048467732
0.053492574
0.05903836
0.065159101
0.071914402
0.079370053
0.08759866
0.096680359
0.106703594
0.117765978
0.129975243
0.14345029
0.158322349
0.174736253
0.192851851
0.212845565
0.234912106
0.259266373
0.286145543
0.315811383
0.348552798
0.384688645
0.424570838
0.468587776
0.517168124
0.570784988
0.629960525
0.695271024
0.76735252
0.84690699
0.934709187
1.031614184
1.138565706
1.256605315
1.386882557
1.530666156
1.689356369
1.864498624
2.057798569
2.271138684
2.506596612
2.766465394
3.053275801
3.369820977
3.719183643
4.104766118
4.530323453
5
```

file "FAS.dat"

```
5.00E-02    7.29E-03
5.03E-02    7.38E-03
5.07E-02    7.46E-03
5.10E-02    7.55E-03
5.14E-02    7.63E-03
5.17E-02    7.72E-03
5.21E-02    7.81E-03
5.24E-02    7.90E-03
5.28E-02    7.99E-03
5.31E-02    8.08E-03
5.35E-02    8.17E-03
5.39E-02    8.27E-03
5.42E-02    8.36E-03
5.46E-02    8.46E-03
5.50E-02    8.55E-03
5.53E-02    8.65E-03
5.57E-02    8.75E-03
5.61E-02    8.84E-03
5.65E-02    8.94E-03
5.68E-02    9.04E-03
5.72E-02    9.14E-03
5.76E-02    9.24E-03
5.80E-02    9.35E-03
5.84E-02    9.45E-03
5.88E-02    9.55E-03
5.92E-02    9.66E-03
5.96E-02    9.76E-03
6.00E-02    9.87E-03
6.04E-02    9.98E-03
6.08E-02    1.01E-02
6.12E-02    1.02E-02
6.16E-02    1.03E-02
6.21E-02    1.04E-02
6.25E-02    1.05E-02
6.29E-02    1.06E-02
6.33E-02    1.08E-02
6.38E-02    1.09E-02
6.42E-02    1.10E-02
6.46E-02    1.11E-02
6.51E-02    1.12E-02
6.55E-02    1.13E-02
6.59E-02    1.15E-02
6.64E-02    1.16E-02
6.68E-02    1.17E-02
6.73E-02    1.18E-02
6.78E-02    1.19E-02
6.82E-02    1.21E-02
6.87E-02    1.22E-02
6.91E-02    1.23E-02
6.96E-02    1.24E-02
7.01E-02    1.26E-02
7.06E-02    1.27E-02
7.10E-02    1.28E-02
7.15E-02    1.30E-02
7.20E-02    1.31E-02
7.25E-02    1.32E-02
7.30E-02    1.33E-02
7.35E-02    1.35E-02
7.40E-02    1.36E-02
7.45E-02    1.37E-02
7.50E-02    1.39E-02
7.55E-02    1.40E-02
7.60E-02    1.42E-02
7.65E-02    1.43E-02
7.70E-02    1.44E-02
7.76E-02    1.46E-02
7.81E-02    1.47E-02
7.86E-02    1.49E-02
7.91E-02    1.50E-02
7.97E-02    1.51E-02
8.02E-02    1.53E-02
8.08E-02    1.54E-02
8.13E-02    1.56E-02
8.19E-02    1.57E-02
8.24E-02    1.59E-02
8.30E-02    1.60E-02
8.35E-02    1.62E-02
8.41E-02    1.63E-02
8.47E-02    1.65E-02
8.52E-02    1.66E-02
8.58E-02    1.68E-02
8.64E-02    1.69E-02
8.70E-02    1.71E-02
8.76E-02    1.72E-02
8.82E-02    1.74E-02
8.88E-02    1.75E-02
8.94E-02    1.77E-02
9.00E-02    1.78E-02
9.06E-02    1.80E-02
9.12E-02    1.81E-02
9.18E-02    1.83E-02
9.24E-02    1.85E-02
9.31E-02    1.86E-02
9.37E-02    1.88E-02
9.43E-02    1.89E-02
9.50E-02    1.91E-02
9.56E-02    1.92E-02
9.63E-02    1.94E-02
9.69E-02    1.96E-02
9.76E-02    1.97E-02
9.82E-02    1.99E-02
9.89E-02    2.01E-02
9.96E-02    2.02E-02
1.00E-01    2.04E-02
1.01E-01    2.05E-02
1.02E-01    2.07E-02
1.02E-01    2.09E-02
1.03E-01    2.10E-02
1.04E-01    2.12E-02
1.04E-01    2.14E-02
1.05E-01    2.15E-02
1.06E-01    2.17E-02
1.07E-01    2.19E-02
1.07E-01    2.20E-02
1.08E-01    2.22E-02
1.09E-01    2.24E-02
1.09E-01    2.25E-02
1.10E-01    2.27E-02
1.11E-01    2.29E-02
1.12E-01    2.30E-02
1.12E-01    2.32E-02
1.13E-01    2.34E-02
1.14E-01    2.36E-02
1.15E-01    2.37E-02
1.16E-01    2.39E-02
1.16E-01    2.41E-02
1.17E-01    2.42E-02
1.18E-01    2.44E-02
1.19E-01    2.46E-02
1.19E-01    2.48E-02
1.20E-01    2.49E-02
1.21E-01    2.51E-02
1.22E-01    2.53E-02
1.23E-01    2.54E-02
1.24E-01    2.56E-02
1.24E-01    2.58E-02
1.25E-01    2.60E-02
1.26E-01    2.61E-02
1.27E-01    2.63E-02
1.28E-01    2.65E-02
1.29E-01    2.66E-02
1.30E-01    2.68E-02
1.30E-01    2.70E-02
1.31E-01    2.72E-02
1.32E-01    2.73E-02
1.33E-01    2.75E-02
1.34E-01    2.77E-02
1.35E-01    2.79E-02
1.36E-01    2.80E-02
1.37E-01    2.82E-02
1.38E-01    2.84E-02
1.39E-01    2.85E-02
1.40E-01    2.87E-02
1.40E-01    2.89E-02
1.41E-01    2.91E-02
1.42E-01    2.92E-02
1.43E-01    2.94E-02
1.44E-01    2.96E-02
1.45E-01    2.97E-02
1.46E-01    2.99E-02
1.47E-01    3.01E-02
1.48E-01    3.03E-02
1.49E-01    3.04E-02
1.50E-01    3.06E-02
1.51E-01    3.08E-02
1.52E-01    3.09E-02
1.53E-01    3.11E-02
1.54E-01    3.13E-02
1.55E-01    3.14E-02
1.57E-01    3.16E-02
1.58E-01    3.18E-02
1.59E-01    3.20E-02
1.60E-01    3.21E-02
1.61E-01    3.23E-02
1.62E-01    3.24E-02
1.63E-01    3.26E-02
1.64E-01    3.27E-02
1.65E-01    3.29E-02
1.66E-01    3.30E-02
1.67E-01    3.32E-02
1.69E-01    3.34E-02
1.70E-01    3.35E-02
1.71E-01    3.37E-02
1.72E-01    3.38E-02
1.73E-01    3.39E-02
1.74E-01    3.41E-02
1.76E-01    3.42E-02
1.77E-01    3.44E-02
1.78E-01    3.45E-02
1.79E-01    3.47E-02
1.80E-01    3.48E-02
1.82E-01    3.50E-02
1.83E-01    3.51E-02
1.84E-01    3.53E-02
1.85E-01    3.54E-02
1.87E-01    3.56E-02
1.88E-01    3.57E-02
1.89E-01    3.58E-02
1.90E-01    3.60E-02
1.92E-01    3.61E-02
1.93E-01    3.63E-02
1.94E-01    3.64E-02
1.96E-01    3.65E-02
1.97E-01    3.67E-02
1.98E-01    3.68E-02
2.00E-01    3.69E-02
2.01E-01    3.71E-02
2.02E-01    3.72E-02
2.04E-01    3.73E-02
2.05E-01    3.75E-02
2.06E-01    3.76E-02
2.08E-01    3.77E-02
2.09E-01    3.79E-02
2.11E-01    3.80E-02
2.12E-01    3.81E-02
2.14E-01    3.83E-02
2.15E-01    3.84E-02
2.16E-01    3.85E-02
2.18E-01    3.87E-02
2.19E-01    3.88E-02
2.21E-01    3.89E-02
2.22E-01    3.90E-02
2.24E-01    3.92E-02
2.25E-01    3.93E-02
2.27E-01    3.94E-02
2.28E-01    3.95E-02
2.30E-01    3.97E-02
2.32E-01    3.98E-02
2.33E-01    3.99E-02
2.35E-01    4.00E-02
2.36E-01    4.01E-02
2.38E-01    4.03E-02
2.40E-01    4.04E-02
2.41E-01    4.05E-02
2.43E-01    4.06E-02
2.44E-01    4.07E-02
2.46E-01    4.09E-02
2.48E-01    4.10E-02
2.49E-01    4.11E-02
2.51E-01    4.12E-02
2.53E-01    4.13E-02
2.55E-01    4.14E-02
2.56E-01    4.16E-02
2.58E-01    4.17E-02
2.60E-01    4.18E-02
2.61E-01    4.19E-02
2.63E-01    4.20E-02
2.65E-01    4.21E-02
2.67E-01    4.22E-02
2.69E-01    4.23E-02
2.70E-01    4.24E-02
2.72E-01    4.25E-02
2.74E-01    4.27E-02
2.76E-01    4.28E-02
2.78E-01    4.29E-02
2.80E-01    4.30E-02
2.82E-01    4.31E-02
2.84E-01    4.32E-02
2.85E-01    4.33E-02
2.87E-01    4.34E-02
2.89E-01    4.35E-02
2.91E-01    4.36E-02
2.93E-01    4.37E-02
2.95E-01    4.38E-02
2.97E-01    4.39E-02
2.99E-01    4.40E-02
3.01E-01    4.41E-02
3.03E-01    4.42E-02
3.05E-01    4.43E-02
3.07E-01    4.44E-02
3.10E-01    4.45E-02
3.12E-01    4.46E-02
3.14E-01    4.47E-02
3.16E-01    4.48E-02
3.18E-01    4.49E-02
3.20E-01    4.50E-02
3.22E-01    4.51E-02
3.25E-01    4.52E-02
3.27E-01    4.53E-02
3.29E-01    4.54E-02
3.31E-01    4.55E-02
3.33E-01    4.56E-02
3.36E-01    4.57E-02
3.38E-01    4.58E-02
3.40E-01    4.59E-02
3.43E-01    4.59E-02
3.45E-01    4.60E-02
3.47E-01    4.61E-02
3.50E-01    4.62E-02
3.52E-01    4.63E-02
3.54E-01    4.64E-02
3.57E-01    4.65E-02
3.59E-01    4.66E-02
3.62E-01    4.67E-02
3.64E-01    4.68E-02
3.66E-01    4.69E-02
3.69E-01    4.69E-02
3.71E-01    4.70E-02
3.74E-01    4.71E-02
3.77E-01    4.72E-02
3.79E-01    4.73E-02
3.82E-01    4.74E-02
3.84E-01    4.75E-02
3.87E-01    4.76E-02
3.89E-01    4.76E-02
3.92E-01    4.77E-02
3.95E-01    4.78E-02
3.97E-01    4.79E-02
4.00E-01    4.80E-02
4.03E-01    4.81E-02
4.06E-01    4.82E-02
4.08E-01    4.82E-02
4.11E-01    4.83E-02
4.14E-01    4.84E-02
4.17E-01    4.85E-02
4.19E-01    4.86E-02
4.22E-01    4.87E-02
4.25E-01    4.88E-02
4.28E-01    4.88E-02
4.31E-01    4.89E-02
4.34E-01    4.90E-02
4.37E-01    4.91E-02
4.40E-01    4.92E-02
4.43E-01    4.93E-02
4.46E-01    4.93E-02
4.49E-01    4.94E-02
4.52E-01    4.95E-02
4.55E-01    4.96E-02
4.58E-01    4.97E-02
4.61E-01    4.97E-02
4.64E-01    4.98E-02
4.67E-01    4.99E-02
4.71E-01    5.00E-02
4.74E-01    5.01E-02
4.77E-01    5.02E-02
4.80E-01    5.02E-02
4.83E-01    5.03E-02
4.87E-01    5.04E-02
4.90E-01    5.05E-02
4.93E-01    5.06E-02
4.97E-01    5.06E-02
5.00E-01    5.07E-02
5.03E-01    5.08E-02
5.07E-01    5.09E-02
5.10E-01    5.10E-02
5.14E-01    5.10E-02
5.17E-01    5.11E-02
5.21E-01    5.11E-02
5.24E-01    5.12E-02
5.28E-01    5.12E-02
5.31E-01    5.13E-02
5.35E-01    5.13E-02
5.39E-01    5.14E-02
5.42E-01    5.15E-02
5.46E-01    5.15E-02
5.50E-01    5.16E-02
5.53E-01    5.16E-02
5.57E-01    5.17E-02
5.61E-01    5.17E-02
5.65E-01    5.18E-02
5.68E-01    5.18E-02
5.72E-01    5.19E-02
5.76E-01    5.19E-02
5.80E-01    5.20E-02
5.84E-01    5.20E-02
5.88E-01    5.21E-02
5.92E-01    5.21E-02
5.96E-01    5.22E-02
6.00E-01    5.22E-02
6.04E-01    5.23E-02
6.08E-01    5.24E-02
6.12E-01    5.24E-02
6.16E-01    5.25E-02
6.21E-01    5.25E-02
6.25E-01    5.26E-02
6.29E-01    5.26E-02
6.33E-01    5.27E-02
6.38E-01    5.27E-02
6.42E-01    5.28E-02
6.46E-01    5.28E-02
6.51E-01    5.29E-02
6.55E-01    5.29E-02
6.59E-01    5.30E-02
6.64E-01    5.30E-02
6.68E-01    5.31E-02
6.73E-01    5.31E-02
6.78E-01    5.32E-02
6.82E-01    5.32E-02
6.87E-01    5.33E-02
6.91E-01    5.33E-02
6.96E-01    5.34E-02
7.01E-01    5.34E-02
7.06E-01    5.35E-02
7.10E-01    5.35E-02
7.15E-01    5.36E-02
7.20E-01    5.36E-02
7.25E-01    5.37E-02
7.30E-01    5.37E-02
7.35E-01    5.38E-02
7.40E-01    5.38E-02
7.45E-01    5.39E-02
7.50E-01    5.39E-02
7.55E-01    5.40E-02
7.60E-01    5.40E-02
7.65E-01    5.41E-02
7.70E-01    5.41E-02
7.76E-01    5.42E-02
7.81E-01    5.42E-02
7.86E-01    5.43E-02
7.91E-01    5.43E-02
7.97E-01    5.44E-02
8.02E-01    5.44E-02
8.08E-01    5.45E-02
8.13E-01    5.45E-02
8.19E-01    5.46E-02
8.24E-01    5.46E-02
8.30E-01    5.47E-02
8.35E-01    5.47E-02
8.41E-01    5.47E-02
8.47E-01    5.48E-02
8.52E-01    5.48E-02
8.58E-01    5.48E-02
8.64E-01    5.49E-02
8.70E-01    5.49E-02
8.76E-01    5.49E-02
8.82E-01    5.50E-02
8.88E-01    5.50E-02
8.94E-01    5.50E-02
9.00E-01    5.51E-02
9.06E-01    5.51E-02
9.12E-01    5.51E-02
9.18E-01    5.51E-02
9.24E-01    5.52E-02
9.31E-01    5.52E-02
9.37E-01    5.52E-02
9.43E-01    5.53E-02
9.50E-01    5.53E-02
9.56E-01    5.53E-02
9.63E-01    5.53E-02
9.69E-01    5.54E-02
9.76E-01    5.54E-02
9.82E-01    5.54E-02
9.89E-01    5.55E-02
9.96E-01    5.55E-02
1.00E+00    5.55E-02
1.01E+00    5.56E-02
1.02E+00    5.56E-02
1.02E+00    5.56E-02
1.03E+00    5.56E-02
1.04E+00    5.57E-02
1.04E+00    5.57E-02
1.05E+00    5.57E-02
1.06E+00    5.58E-02
1.07E+00    5.58E-02
1.07E+00    5.58E-02
1.08E+00    5.58E-02
1.09E+00    5.59E-02
1.09E+00    5.59E-02
1.10E+00    5.59E-02
1.11E+00    5.60E-02
1.12E+00    5.60E-02
1.12E+00    5.60E-02
1.13E+00    5.60E-02
1.14E+00    5.61E-02
1.15E+00    5.61E-02
1.16E+00    5.61E-02
1.16E+00    5.62E-02
1.17E+00    5.62E-02
1.18E+00    5.62E-02
1.19E+00    5.62E-02
1.19E+00    5.63E-02
1.20E+00    5.63E-02
1.21E+00    5.63E-02
1.22E+00    5.64E-02
1.23E+00    5.64E-02
1.24E+00    5.64E-02
1.24E+00    5.64E-02
1.25E+00    5.65E-02
1.26E+00    5.65E-02
1.27E+00    5.65E-02
1.28E+00    5.65E-02
1.29E+00    5.65E-02
1.30E+00    5.65E-02
1.30E+00    5.65E-02
1.31E+00    5.65E-02
1.32E+00    5.65E-02
1.33E+00    5.65E-02
1.34E+00    5.65E-02
1.35E+00    5.65E-02
1.36E+00    5.65E-02
1.37E+00    5.65E-02
1.38E+00    5.65E-02
1.39E+00    5.66E-02
1.40E+00    5.66E-02
1.40E+00    5.66E-02
1.41E+00    5.66E-02
1.42E+00    5.66E-02
1.43E+00    5.66E-02
1.44E+00    5.66E-02
1.45E+00    5.66E-02
1.46E+00    5.66E-02
1.47E+00    5.66E-02
1.48E+00    5.66E-02
1.49E+00    5.66E-02
1.50E+00    5.66E-02
1.51E+00    5.66E-02
1.52E+00    5.66E-02
1.53E+00    5.66E-02
1.54E+00    5.66E-02
1.55E+00    5.66E-02
1.57E+00    5.66E-02
1.58E+00    5.66E-02
1.59E+00    5.66E-02
1.60E+00    5.66E-02
1.61E+00    5.66E-02
1.62E+00    5.66E-02
1.63E+00    5.66E-02
1.64E+00    5.66E-02
1.65E+00    5.66E-02
1.66E+00    5.66E-02
1.67E+00    5.67E-02
1.69E+00    5.67E-02
1.70E+00    5.67E-02
1.71E+00    5.67E-02
1.72E+00    5.67E-02
1.73E+00    5.67E-02
1.74E+00    5.67E-02
1.76E+00    5.67E-02
1.77E+00    5.67E-02
1.78E+00    5.67E-02
1.79E+00    5.67E-02
1.80E+00    5.67E-02
1.82E+00    5.67E-02
1.83E+00    5.67E-02
1.84E+00    5.66E-02
1.85E+00    5.66E-02
1.87E+00    5.66E-02
1.88E+00    5.66E-02
1.89E+00    5.66E-02
1.90E+00    5.66E-02
1.92E+00    5.66E-02
1.93E+00    5.66E-02
1.94E+00    5.66E-02
1.96E+00    5.66E-02
1.97E+00    5.66E-02
1.98E+00    5.66E-02
2.00E+00    5.66E-02
2.01E+00    5.66E-02
2.02E+00    5.66E-02
2.04E+00    5.66E-02
2.05E+00    5.66E-02
2.06E+00    5.66E-02
2.08E+00    5.66E-02
2.09E+00    5.66E-02
2.11E+00    5.66E-02
2.12E+00    5.66E-02
2.14E+00    5.66E-02
2.15E+00    5.66E-02
2.16E+00    5.65E-02
2.18E+00    5.65E-02
2.19E+00    5.65E-02
2.21E+00    5.65E-02
2.22E+00    5.65E-02
2.24E+00    5.65E-02
2.25E+00    5.65E-02
2.27E+00    5.65E-02
2.28E+00    5.64E-02
2.30E+00    5.64E-02
2.32E+00    5.63E-02
2.33E+00    5.62E-02
2.35E+00    5.62E-02
2.36E+00    5.61E-02
2.38E+00    5.61E-02
2.40E+00    5.60E-02
2.41E+00    5.60E-02
2.43E+00    5.59E-02
2.44E+00    5.58E-02
2.46E+00    5.58E-02
2.48E+00    5.57E-02
2.49E+00    5.57E-02
2.51E+00    5.56E-02
2.53E+00    5.55E-02
2.55E+00    5.55E-02
2.56E+00    5.54E-02
2.58E+00    5.54E-02
2.60E+00    5.53E-02
2.61E+00    5.52E-02
2.63E+00    5.52E-02
2.65E+00    5.51E-02
2.67E+00    5.50E-02
2.69E+00    5.50E-02
2.70E+00    5.49E-02
2.72E+00    5.48E-02
2.74E+00    5.48E-02
2.76E+00    5.47E-02
2.78E+00    5.46E-02
2.80E+00    5.46E-02
2.82E+00    5.45E-02
2.84E+00    5.44E-02
2.85E+00    5.44E-02
2.87E+00    5.43E-02
2.89E+00    5.42E-02
2.91E+00    5.42E-02
2.93E+00    5.41E-02
2.95E+00    5.40E-02
2.97E+00    5.39E-02
2.99E+00    5.39E-02
3.01E+00    5.38E-02
3.03E+00    5.37E-02
3.05E+00    5.37E-02
3.07E+00    5.36E-02
3.10E+00    5.35E-02
3.12E+00    5.34E-02
3.14E+00    5.34E-02
3.16E+00    5.33E-02
3.18E+00    5.32E-02
3.20E+00    5.31E-02
3.22E+00    5.29E-02
3.25E+00    5.28E-02
3.27E+00    5.27E-02
3.29E+00    5.26E-02
3.31E+00    5.24E-02
3.33E+00    5.23E-02
3.36E+00    5.22E-02
3.38E+00    5.20E-02
3.40E+00    5.19E-02
3.43E+00    5.18E-02
3.45E+00    5.16E-02
3.47E+00    5.15E-02
3.50E+00    5.14E-02
3.52E+00    5.13E-02
3.54E+00    5.11E-02
3.57E+00    5.10E-02
3.59E+00    5.09E-02
3.62E+00    5.07E-02
3.64E+00    5.06E-02
3.66E+00    5.05E-02
3.69E+00    5.03E-02
3.71E+00    5.02E-02
3.74E+00    5.00E-02
3.77E+00    4.99E-02
3.79E+00    4.98E-02
3.82E+00    4.96E-02
3.84E+00    4.95E-02
3.87E+00    4.94E-02
3.89E+00    4.92E-02
3.92E+00    4.91E-02
3.95E+00    4.89E-02
3.97E+00    4.88E-02
4.00E+00    4.86E-02
4.03E+00    4.85E-02
4.06E+00    4.84E-02
4.08E+00    4.82E-02
4.11E+00    4.81E-02
4.14E+00    4.79E-02
4.17E+00    4.78E-02
4.19E+00    4.76E-02
4.22E+00    4.75E-02
4.25E+00    4.73E-02
4.28E+00    4.72E-02
4.31E+00    4.71E-02
4.34E+00    4.69E-02
4.37E+00    4.68E-02
4.40E+00    4.66E-02
4.43E+00    4.65E-02
4.46E+00    4.63E-02
4.49E+00    4.62E-02
4.52E+00    4.60E-02
4.55E+00    4.59E-02
4.58E+00    4.57E-02
4.61E+00    4.56E-02
4.64E+00    4.54E-02
4.67E+00    4.52E-02
4.71E+00    4.51E-02
4.74E+00    4.49E-02
4.77E+00    4.48E-02
4.80E+00    4.46E-02
4.83E+00    4.45E-02
4.87E+00    4.43E-02
4.90E+00    4.42E-02
4.93E+00    4.40E-02
4.97E+00    4.38E-02
5.00E+00    4.37E-02
5.03E+00    4.35E-02
5.07E+00    4.34E-02
5.10E+00    4.32E-02
5.14E+00    4.30E-02
5.17E+00    4.29E-02
5.21E+00    4.27E-02
5.24E+00    4.26E-02
5.28E+00    4.24E-02
5.31E+00    4.22E-02
5.35E+00    4.21E-02
5.39E+00    4.19E-02
5.42E+00    4.17E-02
5.46E+00    4.16E-02
5.50E+00    4.14E-02
5.53E+00    4.13E-02
5.57E+00    4.11E-02
5.61E+00    4.09E-02
5.65E+00    4.08E-02
5.68E+00    4.06E-02
5.72E+00    4.04E-02
5.76E+00    4.03E-02
5.80E+00    4.01E-02
5.84E+00    3.99E-02
5.88E+00    3.97E-02
5.92E+00    3.96E-02
5.96E+00    3.94E-02
6.00E+00    3.92E-02
6.04E+00    3.91E-02
6.08E+00    3.89E-02
6.12E+00    3.87E-02
6.16E+00    3.84E-02
6.21E+00    3.82E-02
6.25E+00    3.80E-02
6.29E+00    3.78E-02
6.33E+00    3.76E-02
6.38E+00    3.74E-02
6.42E+00    3.72E-02
6.46E+00    3.70E-02
6.51E+00    3.68E-02
6.55E+00    3.65E-02
6.59E+00    3.63E-02
6.64E+00    3.61E-02
6.68E+00    3.59E-02
6.73E+00    3.57E-02
6.78E+00    3.55E-02
6.82E+00    3.53E-02
6.87E+00    3.51E-02
6.91E+00    3.48E-02
6.96E+00    3.46E-02
7.01E+00    3.44E-02
7.06E+00    3.42E-02
7.10E+00    3.40E-02
7.15E+00    3.38E-02
7.20E+00    3.36E-02
7.25E+00    3.34E-02
7.30E+00    3.31E-02
7.35E+00    3.29E-02
7.40E+00    3.27E-02
7.45E+00    3.25E-02
7.50E+00    3.23E-02
7.55E+00    3.21E-02
7.60E+00    3.19E-02
7.65E+00    3.17E-02
7.70E+00    3.15E-02
7.76E+00    3.12E-02
7.81E+00    3.10E-02
7.86E+00    3.08E-02
7.91E+00    3.06E-02
7.97E+00    3.04E-02
8.02E+00    3.02E-02
8.08E+00    3.00E-02
8.13E+00    2.98E-02
8.19E+00    2.95E-02
8.24E+00    2.93E-02
8.30E+00    2.91E-02
8.35E+00    2.89E-02
8.41E+00    2.87E-02
8.47E+00    2.85E-02
8.52E+00    2.83E-02
8.58E+00    2.81E-02
8.64E+00    2.79E-02
8.70E+00    2.77E-02
8.76E+00    2.74E-02
8.82E+00    2.72E-02
8.88E+00    2.70E-02
8.94E+00    2.68E-02
9.00E+00    2.66E-02
9.06E+00    2.64E-02
9.12E+00    2.62E-02
9.18E+00    2.60E-02
9.24E+00    2.58E-02
9.31E+00    2.56E-02
9.37E+00    2.54E-02
9.43E+00    2.52E-02
9.50E+00    2.50E-02
9.56E+00    2.48E-02
9.63E+00    2.46E-02
9.69E+00    2.43E-02
9.76E+00    2.41E-02
9.82E+00    2.39E-02
9.89E+00    2.37E-02
9.96E+00    2.35E-02
1.00E+01    2.33E-02
1.01E+01    2.31E-02
1.02E+01    2.29E-02
1.02E+01    2.27E-02
1.03E+01    2.25E-02
1.04E+01    2.23E-02
1.04E+01    2.21E-02
1.05E+01    2.19E-02
1.06E+01    2.17E-02
1.07E+01    2.15E-02
1.07E+01    2.13E-02
1.08E+01    2.11E-02
1.09E+01    2.09E-02
1.09E+01    2.07E-02
1.10E+01    2.06E-02
1.11E+01    2.04E-02
1.12E+01    2.02E-02
1.12E+01    2.00E-02
1.13E+01    1.98E-02
1.14E+01    1.96E-02
1.15E+01    1.94E-02
1.16E+01    1.92E-02
1.16E+01    1.90E-02
1.17E+01    1.88E-02
1.18E+01    1.86E-02
1.19E+01    1.84E-02
1.19E+01    1.83E-02
1.20E+01    1.81E-02
1.21E+01    1.79E-02
1.22E+01    1.77E-02
1.23E+01    1.75E-02
1.24E+01    1.73E-02
1.24E+01    1.72E-02
1.25E+01    1.70E-02
1.26E+01    1.68E-02
1.27E+01    1.66E-02
1.28E+01    1.64E-02
1.29E+01    1.62E-02
1.30E+01    1.61E-02
1.30E+01    1.59E-02
1.31E+01    1.57E-02
1.32E+01    1.55E-02
1.33E+01    1.54E-02
1.34E+01    1.52E-02
1.35E+01    1.50E-02
1.36E+01    1.48E-02
1.37E+01    1.47E-02
1.38E+01    1.45E-02
1.39E+01    1.43E-02
1.40E+01    1.42E-02
1.40E+01    1.40E-02
1.41E+01    1.38E-02
1.42E+01    1.37E-02
1.43E+01    1.35E-02
1.44E+01    1.33E-02
1.45E+01    1.32E-02
1.46E+01    1.30E-02
1.47E+01    1.28E-02
1.48E+01    1.27E-02
1.49E+01    1.25E-02
1.50E+01    1.24E-02
1.51E+01    1.22E-02
1.52E+01    1.21E-02
1.53E+01    1.19E-02
1.54E+01    1.17E-02
1.55E+01    1.16E-02
1.57E+01    1.14E-02
1.58E+01    1.13E-02
1.59E+01    1.11E-02
1.60E+01    1.10E-02
1.61E+01    1.08E-02
1.62E+01    1.07E-02
1.63E+01    1.05E-02
1.64E+01    1.04E-02
1.65E+01    1.03E-02
1.66E+01    1.01E-02
1.67E+01    9.95E-03
1.69E+01    9.80E-03
1.70E+01    9.65E-03
1.71E+01    9.50E-03
1.72E+01    9.35E-03
1.73E+01    9.20E-03
1.74E+01    9.06E-03
1.76E+01    8.91E-03
1.77E+01    8.77E-03
1.78E+01    8.63E-03
1.79E+01    8.49E-03
1.80E+01    8.35E-03
1.82E+01    8.21E-03
1.83E+01    8.08E-03
1.84E+01    7.94E-03
1.85E+01    7.81E-03
1.87E+01    7.68E-03
1.88E+01    7.55E-03
1.89E+01    7.42E-03
1.90E+01    7.29E-03
1.92E+01    7.17E-03
1.93E+01    7.04E-03
1.94E+01    6.92E-03
1.96E+01    6.80E-03
1.97E+01    6.68E-03
1.98E+01    6.56E-03
2.00E+01    6.44E-03
2.01E+01    6.32E-03
2.02E+01    6.21E-03
2.04E+01    6.09E-03
2.05E+01    5.98E-03
2.06E+01    5.87E-03
2.08E+01    5.76E-03
2.09E+01    5.65E-03
2.11E+01    5.55E-03
2.12E+01    5.44E-03
2.14E+01    5.34E-03
2.15E+01    5.23E-03
2.16E+01    5.13E-03
2.18E+01    5.03E-03
2.19E+01    4.93E-03
2.21E+01    4.84E-03
2.22E+01    4.74E-03
2.24E+01    4.64E-03
2.25E+01    4.55E-03
2.27E+01    4.46E-03
2.28E+01    4.37E-03
2.30E+01    4.28E-03
2.32E+01    4.19E-03
2.33E+01    4.10E-03
2.35E+01    4.02E-03
2.36E+01    3.93E-03
2.38E+01    3.85E-03
2.40E+01    3.77E-03
2.41E+01    3.69E-03
2.43E+01    3.61E-03
2.44E+01    3.53E-03
2.46E+01    3.45E-03
2.48E+01    3.37E-03
2.49E+01    3.30E-03
2.51E+01    3.23E-03
2.53E+01    3.15E-03
2.55E+01    3.08E-03
2.56E+01    3.01E-03
2.58E+01    2.94E-03
2.60E+01    2.87E-03
2.61E+01    2.81E-03
2.63E+01    2.74E-03
2.65E+01    2.68E-03
2.67E+01    2.61E-03
2.69E+01    2.55E-03
2.70E+01    2.49E-03
2.72E+01    2.43E-03
2.74E+01    2.37E-03
2.76E+01    2.31E-03
2.78E+01    2.26E-03
2.80E+01    2.20E-03
2.82E+01    2.15E-03
2.84E+01    2.09E-03
2.85E+01    2.04E-03
2.87E+01    1.99E-03
2.89E+01    1.94E-03
2.91E+01    1.89E-03
2.93E+01    1.84E-03
2.95E+01    1.79E-03
2.97E+01    1.74E-03
2.99E+01    1.70E-03
3.01E+01    1.65E-03
3.03E+01    1.61E-03
3.05E+01    1.57E-03
3.07E+01    1.52E-03
3.10E+01    1.48E-03
3.12E+01    1.44E-03
3.14E+01    1.40E-03
3.16E+01    1.36E-03
3.18E+01    1.32E-03
3.20E+01    1.29E-03
3.22E+01    1.25E-03
3.25E+01    1.21E-03
3.27E+01    1.18E-03
3.29E+01    1.15E-03
3.31E+01    1.11E-03
3.33E+01    1.08E-03
3.36E+01    1.05E-03
3.38E+01    1.02E-03
3.40E+01    9.87E-04
3.43E+01    9.57E-04
3.45E+01    9.29E-04
3.47E+01    9.00E-04
3.50E+01    8.73E-04
3.52E+01    8.46E-04
3.54E+01    8.20E-04
3.57E+01    7.94E-04
3.59E+01    7.69E-04
3.62E+01    7.45E-04
3.64E+01    7.21E-04
3.66E+01    6.98E-04
3.69E+01    6.76E-04
3.71E+01    6.54E-04
3.74E+01    6.32E-04
3.77E+01    6.12E-04
3.79E+01    5.92E-04
3.82E+01    5.72E-04
3.84E+01    5.53E-04
3.87E+01    5.34E-04
3.89E+01    5.16E-04
3.92E+01    4.98E-04
3.95E+01    4.81E-04
3.97E+01    4.65E-04
4.00E+01    4.48E-04
4.03E+01    4.33E-04
4.06E+01    4.18E-04
4.08E+01    4.03E-04
4.11E+01    3.88E-04
4.14E+01    3.74E-04
4.17E+01    3.61E-04
4.19E+01    3.48E-04
4.22E+01    3.35E-04
4.25E+01    3.23E-04
4.28E+01    3.11E-04
4.31E+01    2.99E-04
4.34E+01    2.88E-04
4.37E+01    2.77E-04
4.40E+01    2.66E-04
4.43E+01    2.56E-04
4.46E+01    2.46E-04
4.49E+01    2.37E-04
4.52E+01    2.28E-04
4.55E+01    2.19E-04
4.58E+01    2.10E-04
4.61E+01    2.02E-04
4.64E+01    1.94E-04
4.67E+01    1.86E-04
4.71E+01    1.78E-04
4.74E+01    1.71E-04
4.77E+01    1.64E-04
4.80E+01    1.57E-04
4.83E+01    1.51E-04
4.87E+01    1.44E-04
4.90E+01    1.38E-04
4.93E+01    1.32E-04
4.97E+01    1.27E-04
5.00E+01    1.21E-04
```

Comment: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Measure-performance-with-[@time](@ref)-and-pay-attention-to-memory-allocation-1

Comment: Also a few [`@inbounds`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.@inbounds) to eliminate bounds checking will help for performance.

Comment: One small tip: Creating a complex vector `H` only to later return `abs.(H)` is wasteful. Just directly calculate `H[i] = abs((-fn^2) / ((f^2-fn^2) - (2im*f*fn*D)))`. Or, faster and better: `H[i] = fn^2 / sqrt((f^2-fn^2)^2 + (2*f*fn*D)^2)`. This is also true for your Matlab code. Don't make unnecessary temporary arrays.

Answer (score 2):

The first time you run Julia, it compiles everything, this takes a little bit of time. The second time anything gets called, it is already compiled and lightening fast.

Call your function twice, the second call will be much faster.

When I run it my first call is `2.750975 seconds` and second call is `0.013358 seconds`

What I mean by two call is this:

```
@time SA,PF=FAS2SA(FAS1,f_FAS,10.0,f_SA, 0.05) <---2.750975 seconds
@time SA,PF=FAS2SA(FAS1,f_FAS,10.0,f_SA, 0.05) <---0.013358 seconds
```

For timing, using BenchmarkTools is better, it calls it several times for you. replace

`println(@time SA,PF=FAS2SA(FAS1,f_FAS,10.0,f_SA, 0.05))`

with
`using BenchmarkTools`

`@btime FAS2SA($FAS1,$f_FAS,10.0,$f_SA, 0.05)`

the output is `10.669 ms (125187 allocations: 6.17 MiB)`

Notice how many allocations and memory you are using. this means your code could still be much faster. I am not going to optimize it, it is too long. But I guarantee you can make your code considerably faster if you get rid of all those allocations.

With practice, you will be able to write code that is as fast as C and Fortran (I have seen it several times now on non-trivial code), but it does take practice. You need to avoid making temporary arrays.

I recommend reading these tips at the very least:

[https://docs.julialang.org/performance-tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/index.html)